# Dialog Box like JOptionPane in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to add border like message box in windows using codenameone dialog box but I am not able to do it.

Can anyone give me some suggestion.  This is what i tried. but its not
working properly.

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog("---MESSAGE---");

    dialog.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    dialog.getStyle().setMargin(2,250);

    dialog.getStyle().setPadding(2,250);

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: What's a border like message box in JOptionPane? I'm unfamiliar with that option?

Comment: Actually i mean to say normal message box look and feel like in java swing.How can i make my codenameone dialog box like java swing message box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use themeing http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html

They go far beyond what's available in Swing's look and feel. The JOptionPane as it is was desktop specific and doesn't fit on mobile.

Comment: But i am not using GUI builder.I want to do it by coding only.so  by coding ,how can i create theme ?

Comment: Using the designer for the theme has nothing to do with the container. You can use getUnselected/SelectedStyle() and manually customize everything but that's unnecessary. Themeing is used in these handcoded apps: https://www.udemy.com/learn-mobile-programming-by-example-with-codename-one/ http://codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-1.html